# POST Method not working in form submission?

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

I've set up a  product enquiry page so that people can submit questions straight from the product details page.
I'd like to post some variables from the product details page to the enquiry page, but when I use the POST method it does not work (I'm re-directed to a search page). I assume this is a security measure and is being controlled by auth.php (or a file referenced from there).It works fine when I use GET, but i want to avoid the variables in URL.
My page looks like this

Code:

```
require "./auth.php";
require $xcart_dir."/include/categories.php";
require "products.php";
$smarty->assign("main","productenquiry");
func_display("customer/home.tpl", $smarty);
```

Answer (score 0):

afaics, it's a restriction posed from your web server administrator..imho, it has nothing to do with auth.php

A friend of mine had a similar issue and after much exercise we came to know upon contacting that the web administrators had done something which was causing the issue and on our request the same was resolved and we were able to use POST method..

So, you may try to contact your web server administrator to resolve the same..

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you should do is make sure that `$_POST` actually works.
To do that, create a basic form,  then submit it to a php file that contains just `<?php var_dump($_POST);`. This will show you exactly what is being passed through.

Break the problem into small steps.